# Optimal pattern for modals in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I have a need for multiple modals in my app. I'm thinking about the optimal way to manage modal state. From what I researched and from what I know about React, I see two ways to manage it.

1) Using React useState hook to manage modal's state in every component that possibly shows the modal.

2) Using Context API to create context and state at the top of the component tree and accessing the state in every component that possibly shows the modal using useContext hook.

Both of these approaches seem very similar to me.

```
const [isOpened, toggleModal] = useState(false)
```

vs

```
const [isOpened, toggleModal] = useContext(ModalContext)
```

Is one of these approaches better than the other in the matter of performance? The amount of code needed for each is nearly the same. Or if there is any better solution, I would appreciate the insight! Thank you.